# How to read the first frame of video using OpenCV in python?

Tags: python, opencv

Here is some code I am using which should succeed in returning the first frame of a video. The relevant bits here I think are lines 2:5 and the second to last one where count=2.

```
def define_bounds(video_file, threshold_value, index_value):
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)
    count=0
    while count <1:
        success,color_img = vidcap.read()
        blkwht_img = np.asarray(Image.fromarray(color_img).convert('L'))[index_value]
        retval, final_img = cv2.threshold(blkwht_img, threshold_value, 200, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C)
        for pixel_row in range(139,-1,-1): 
           if np.median(final_img[pixel_row,:]) <10:
               silenced = pixel_row - 2
               upmotion = pixel_row - 16
               destination = pixel_row - 44
               downmotion = pixel_row - 31
               break
       count=2
   return silenced, upmotion, destination, downmotion
```

I do know for a fact that vidcap.read() succeeds in reading frames from the first to the last (I have other code I use to determine this, where it just exports all frames from first to last).

But this code above fails in reading the first frame... it reads SOME frame but I don't know which. It's not the first, second or last as the output of the function does not match when I manually input the first, second and last frames.

Is there something stupidly wrong in my code? Also: am I using break correctly? I'm still new to this. Thanks!

Comment: The line `count = 2` is not properly indented. If  `count` is set to 2 after the while loop, then your function will not work as per the expectation.

Comment: usually python yells at me if things aren't indented correctly. why would that not be the case here? thanks